# Sort/Filter an array to dictionaries based on date

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, nspredicate

I was stumped with this question a few weeks ago. Say you have the following structure:

```
@interface SomeObject : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSDate *someDate;
@end

RLMArray<SomeObject *> *array = ... // Assume that this array is filled with a bunch of objects
```

Is it possible to turn the array into the following structure?

```
NSDictionary *desiredDict = @{
@"5": // The month of someDate
@[[SomeObject ...]], // An array of objects that have that month
...}
```

Whereas the keys in the dictionary represent the month of `someDate`?

**Purpose:**

Say you're working with a backend that returns an unsorted array of objects that contain a date, how would you convert them to a dictionary whereas keys in the dictionary correspond to the month of the objects?

I suppose you could write an algorithm to take care of this, however, it would be interesting to see if anyone has any other ideas. Perhaps by utilizing `NSPredicate`'s?

Comment: This is a common task on `UITableView` with sections. For instance something that could inspire you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898466/uitableview-dynamically-create-sections-from-nsarray

Comment: True. However, my question relates to what you would do to transform an array to a dictionary (with arrays) to make it fit sections/rows :)

Comment: It's the exact same approach, except that `firstLetter` becomes in your case monthNumber.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630088/4667835) answer of mine for a similar question. You should be able to translate the Swift code to Objective-C and it shows how to create a `Dictionary` whose keys are days represented as `Date` objects and its values are all objects whose `Date` property is on that specific day. You can easily convert the day approach to months.